# How to display only the group name and color without the subgroups items in the print composer?

Tags: print-composer

I have a polygon of Africa with each country in a different colour. I want my legend to show only the word "Africa" without the names of the countries. I also want to have Africa with a blue colours like the countries.

Right now all I get is this legend:

[image: Legend]

Can anyone help me with this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove specific legend entries (country names here), select them and use the red minus sign below. If you select and remove them all, you will end-up with just the layer name.

BUT, it doesn't allow you to set a style for the layer name. The easiest would be to duplicate the layer (on your map), set it all in blue, don't display it but use it for the legend.